# Adding Fgallery into my app

Tags: project, addition

I would appreciate it if someone could show me (step by step), how to add an external project to an exiting app. I've been trying on my own but so far I haven't succeeded.

So how do I add Fgallery to my storyboard app?

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone

I'm doing this to learn so please don't get to technical with the talk, just show me and I will try to understand each step on my own. that's how I learn :)

Many thanks for your time!

Comment: are you trying to display local images or images from the web?

Answer (score 0):

first you add fgalleryappdelegate.h/m, fgalleryphoto.h/m, fgalleryphotoview.h/m, fgalleryviewcontroller.h/m and rootviewcontroller.h/m. you then edit the rootview controllers according to what you want and then you add a navigation controller to your storyboard and connect it to rootviewcontroller.

then you edit this part in rootview.m in order to get to your own pictures

## pragma mark - View lifecycle

```
- (void)loadView {
[super loadView];

self.title = @"FGallery";
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;

localCaptions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Lava", @"Hawaii", @"Audi", @"Happy New Year!",@"Frosty Web",nil];
localImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"lava.jpeg", @"hawaii.jpeg", @"audi.jpg",nil];

networkCaptions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Happy New Year!",@"Frosty Web",nil];
networkImages = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5042/5323996646_9c11e1b2f6_b.jpg", @"http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5007/5311573633_3cae940638.jpg",nil];
```

}